# How do I make XPath expressions more generic?

Tags: xpath, xpathnavigator

I have xpath expressions for a navigation tree which contains some child branches whicjh can be added:

```
/html/body/div[@id='application-wrapper']/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/**div[1]**/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[@id='gwt-uid-17']/a

/html/body/div[@id='application-wrapper']/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/**div[2]**/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[@id='gwt-uid-58']/a

/html/body/div[@id='application-wrapper']/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/**div[3]**/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[@id='gwt-uid-83']/a
```

i need to make it generic statement similar to the given below but unable to do it

```
//div[@role='treeitem']/a[text()='Situation']/ancestor::table//div[1]//a
```

Can some one shed some light?

**Update from comments**

> I can see 3 child nodes[ div[1] in
>   first expression, div[2] in second
>   expression and div[3] in third
>   expression] so instead of writing till
>   div[100] i want to put it as div[%d]
>   but I am unable to do so

Comment: Please explain, in English, exactly what nodes you want. Ultimately this will lead to a robust XPath expression.

Comment: I can see 3 child nodes[ div[1] in first expression, div[2] in second expression and div[3] in third expression] so instead of writing till div[100] i want to put it as div[%d] but I am unable to do so

Comment: I believe you don't care about those divs, correct? You want links of some sort. Please explain *exactly* what you want to extract.

Comment: What I mean is statements like "all the links in the box with a 'price' heading". Starting with Firebug XPaths is absolutely the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: i dont care abt divs at all. what I want is a generic div which when i enter an integer will take me to that particular child node.

Comment: My tree item can have any number of child branches with heading "situation" and for every test case i write i need to go into a particular situation - 1 or situation-2

Comment: You know, this would be a lot easier if you provided sample XML and showed us the node you want.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two single XPath expressions (one very short and possibly inefficient, the other quite long, but more efficient), that select exactly the wanted three `a` elements.

Answer (score 1):

**If the values of the `id` attributes uniquely identify the elements**, then a short expression that selects exactly all these three `a` elements is:

```
//div[@id='gwt-uid-17' or @id='gwt-uid-58' or @id='gwt-uid-83']/a
```

However, evaluating the `//` abbreviation can be very inefficient and is not recommended.

**A single XPath expression that select these three `a` elements and will be more efficient is**:

```
/html/body/div[@id='application-wrapper']/div/div[2]/div/div[3]
   /div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[not(position() >3)]/div[1]
    /table/tbody/tr/td[2]
     /div[@id='gwt-uid-17' or @id='gwt-uid-58' or @id='gwt-uid-83']/a
```

Comment: The problem is that the "efficient" expression will break easily, even if unrelated parts of the page change. In general, I wouldn't recommend that strategy for HTML parsing.

Comment: I think this is almost the answer. Check my update to question from comments.

Comment: @Mark-Thomas: What you refer to parsing is actually screen-scraping. Any XPath expression is evaluated only after the XML document is parsed (once and forever) completely. So, not "parisng", but "evaluation" -- let's have the basics correct as a start...

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the shortest expression that uniquely identifies the node(s) you want. For example, the expression

```
//div[@id='gwt-uid-17']/a
```

is equivalent to the first line above, because ids are unique (supposedly).

If you want to target links under the "Situation" link, you can try

```
//a[text()='Situation']//table//a[1]
```

but I'd need to see the XML to know if that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is valid XHTML, and that `id` is actually a unique identifier, you don't need any of the hierarchy above the specified `div`s, and can use an XPath expressions like this:

```
//div[@id='gwt-uid-17']/a
```

Depending on your language binding, you can also use variables in your XPath expressions, so could use a generic expression like this:

```
//div[@id='$theDivIWant']/a
```